# NativeScript (Angular) APK release errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new to NativeScript. I am try to release an APK using

```
tns build android --for-device --release --bundle --env.aot --env.production --key-store-path ./release.keystore --key-store-password app-Release@2018 --key-store-alias app --key-store-alias-password app12345
```

An I am getting errors like this.

```
ERROR in ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/nmm/anu/projectname/app/auth/auth.module.ngfactory.js' in '/home/nmm/anu/projectname/$$_lazy_route_resource'
     @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ./auth/auth.module.ngfactory
     @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
     @ ./app.module.ts
     @ ./main.ts
```

Here is my module file

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete/angular/autocomplete-directives";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular/listview-directives";
import { TNSCheckBoxModule } from "nativescript-checkbox/angular";
import { RadioButtonModule } from "@webileapps/nativescript-radiobutton/angular";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { CommonFormsModule } from "~/common-forms/common-forms.module";
import { AdoptGrandParentComponent } from "./adopt-grand-parent.component";

const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "adopt-grandparent", pathMatch: "full"},
    { path: "adopt-grandparent", component: AdoptGrandParentComponent}
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),
        RadioButtonModule,
        TNSCheckBoxModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule,
        CommonFormsModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AdoptGrandParentComponent
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: [],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class AdoptGrandParentModule {

}
```

Comment: Which version of {N} & Webpack dev plugin you are using?

Comment: "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.19.2" and nativescript version: "5.3.1"

Comment: That's too old, if you are unable to upgrade your app at this time I would suggest you to go through the [issues on webpack repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack), you might find a solution. You may also try building without aot, possibly its an issue with AOT build.